# How can I convert this inline ASM to a separate file, to be able to compile the project to x64?

Tags: c++

I want to compile this project in the x64 architecture, but I cant use _asm because it will freak out and will not compile.
Here's the code snippet:

```
int FloatConstNode::intValue(){
    float flt=value;
    int temp;
    _control87( _RC_NEAR|_PC_24|_EM_INVALID|_EM_ZERODIVIDE|_EM_OVERFLOW|_EM_UNDERFLOW|_EM_INEXACT|_EM_DENORMAL,0xfffff );
    _asm
    {
        fld [flt];
        fistp [temp];
    }
    _control87( _CW_DEFAULT,0xfffff );
    return temp;
}
```

I also heard I need to convert it to x64 assembly, and I dont know how.
Any help?

Comment: I don't remember what all of these flags mean, but I have a strong feeling that you achieve the same effect in pure c++.

Comment: Avoid inline asm when at all possible (which is *Almost always*). Prefer readable C++ code instead.

Comment: You can use the [facilities](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv) provided by the language to manipulate the floating point environment (replacing the platform specific `_control87` function) and replace the asm code with C++.